# Making connection-string easy modifiable

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I don't know if I've become too stupid for proper googling but I didn't find a solution to this:

I have an asp.net application with ado.net Framework and therefore there is a connection-string.

My connection-string is stored in the Web.config like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=x.x.x.x;User Id=user;password=1234;database=db;port=8888;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have to give the solution to some people, and I find it kinda annoying if they had to dig into this connection-string and change all the settings there (it's just not "clear-arranged" in there), it would be nice if I could declare them outside the string, maybe like this (in the same file or if possible also in another file called "dbsettings" and include this file in the web.config) :

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="dbserver" value="x.x.x.x" />
 <add key="dbserverport" value="8888" />
 <add key="dbuser" value="user" />
 <add key="dbpassword" value="1234" />
</appSettings>
```

I hope you get what I'm talking about.

---

**Solution**

First of all view ChiYoung answer - he said almost everything, but anyway here in detail how I did it:

In `Web.config` I added this (inside of the `configuration`section):

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="dbserver" value="x.x.x.x" />
 <add key="dbserverport" value="8888" />
 <add key="dbname" value="dbxy" />
 <add key="dbuser" value="user" />
 <add key="dbpassword" value="1234" />
</appSettings>
```

Then I created a class `DatabaseHelper.cs`in my `Data`-Layer (Project), which looks like this:

```
class DatabaseHelper
{
    public static string MakeConnectionString()
    {
        string appDbserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbserver"];
        string appDbserverport = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbserverport"];
        string appDbuser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbuser"];
        string appDbpassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbpassword"];
        string appDbname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbname"];

        return @"metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=""server=" + appDbserver + @";User Id=" +
               appDbuser + @";password=" + appDbpassword + @";database="+appDbname+@";port=" + appDbserverport + @";Persist Security Info=True""";
    }
}
```

Next I changed my `DataModel.Designer.cs` file (this class inherits from `ObjectContext`and was auto generated since I'm working with Ado.net), I changed the generated constructor from:

```
    public Entities() : base("name=Entities", "Entities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();

    }
```

to:

```
    public Entities() : base(DatabaseHelper.MakeConnectionString(), "Entities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

If you have a project which is not related to the Web project - in my case it was a test-project you have to add the appsettings to the related config file (`App.config / Web.config`).

Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.config :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionString.config" />
</configuration>
```

In your new file connectionString.config (This is the only code in that file!) :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Or like you are doing :

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="dbserver" value="x.x.x.x" />
 <add key="dbserverport" value="8888" />
 <add key="dbuser" value="user" />
 <add key="dbpassword" value="1234" />
</appSettings>
```

And then concatenating your string :

```
string appDbserver= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbserver"];
string appDbserverport= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbserverport"];
string appDbuser= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbuser"];
string appDbpassword= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbpassword"];

string myConnectionstring = @"metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=" + appDbserver + @";User Id=" + appDbuser + @";password=" + appDbpassword + @";database=db;port=" + appDbserverport + @";Persist Security Info=True&quot;"
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost what I want, but when I look on your code, it looks like I have to make this connection string with c# then (in which file btw?) - I would prefer if it'd be possible if I could use these "key" variables right inside the xml like `<connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbserver"];> ` - you know what I mean? is this possible?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which file you store this function, but lets suppose you do it in functions.cs in a namespace "myfunctions" than you could create a static function like myConnectionString() and use it in all your other pages by using a reference like using myFunctions; You can find more on using functions with dynamic connectionstring on following url http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/217366/dynamically-set-connection-string-in-web-config

Comment: ok I think I got it, would be nice if you could review my solution above if it's ok like this. Anyway I marked your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: It's a nice way to use your connection string :)